# How to elasticsearch compound queries from android client?

Tags: android, elasticsearch, retrofit2

I use firestore as `db` and one elasticsearch instance. I trigger cloud functions to put data to elastic server. I am using elasticsearch because I need compound queries to retrieve data. I can send basic queries with retrofit. I am a newbie about that subject, and I am looking for some sources to learn compound queries with **es+andorid+retrofit**, or any other way to do it. Do you have any suggestions?

I mean how to write the query below in android retrofit

```
{
"query": {
    "match_all": {}
},
"filter": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
            {
                "term": {
                    "city": "New york"
                }
            },
            {
                "term": {
                    "state": "NY"
                }
            },
            {
                "bool": {
                    "should": [
                        {
                            "bool": {
                                "must": [
                                    {
                                        "term": {
                                            "businessName": "Java"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "term": {
                                            "businessName": "Shop"
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "bool": {
                                "must": [
                                    {
                                        "term": {
                                            "category": "Java"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "term": {
                                            "category": "Shop"
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution from these pages:

https://www.compose.com/articles/using-query-string-queries-in-elasticsearch/
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-uri-request.html

Answer (score 0):

Actually your question isn't clear. if u can run basic query then, it's logically can run compound query. However if you asking to retrieve data both from elastic instance as well as firestore instance at once, then you should create a new service/api instance which accepts request from mobile and looking for result from both instance then merge and send back to mobile, otherwise merging response from two service/api from mobile end will affects performance/user experience.